# Sitecore tree expand event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone know which event/pipeline/command I can hook into when someone clicks on a item node to expand the tree?

Comment: I believe it occurs asynchronously. You might try extending the itemsync:loadtree command... just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people post solutions for various things when a user clicks or interacts with an item that impacts the tree node.  I think it would be easier if you could describe how you're trying to interact with the tree nodes.  But to help, I believe you want to look in the RenderContentEditor pipeline.